# Regex for matching substring in JavaScript using VCS

Tags: javascript, regex, expression, match

I'm currently working on a short program in JavaScript that matches substrings within string, with a wildcard character in between.

```
let string1 = "The man is outside.";
let string2 = "I have two minutes.";
let string3 = "The men are here.";
```

I'm trying to find a regex expression that will encompass "m_n".

I've been trying to use the following function:

```
let matching = function(string) {
    if (string.match(^m.*n$)) {
        console.log("it does");
    }
    else {
        console.log("it doesnt");
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ^".

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: Do you want it to be its own word or is within another work okay?  `/\bm.n\b/` if its own word.  A single wildcard character in between?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you forgot to assign / (forward slash).
And I recommend use **test** instead of **match** in if statement.

```js
let string = "msdfsxn";
if (/^m.*n$/.test(string)) {
   console.log("it does");
} else {
   console.log("it doesn't");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that maybe,

```
m[^n]n
```

or

```
\bm[^n]n\b
```

or

```
\bm.*?n\b
```

might be close, or maybe not.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/N9Tf31/1/)

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/PUSH8Y/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uLvBgv/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/uLvBgv/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

```js
const regex = /m[^n]n/gm;
const str = `The man is outside.
I have two minutes.
The men are here.`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```